# How to stop AVAudioPlayer once we navigate from one view to into other view in iOS8?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, avaudioplayer

I am fresher to iOS. I am using `AVFoundation` framework for `AVAudioPlayer`.  This is used for running background sound when user enters into application home screen.  This background sound should be stopped when it goes to other views and should be enabled when user come back to the home screen again.  Below code is working fine in IOS7, when I upgrade to IOS8 background sound continuously playing and doesn’t stop when I go to other views. Kindly help me in this issue.

I am using below code for start and stop the player

```
NSString *pewPewPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *pewPewURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pewPewPath];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pewPewURL];
audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data1 error:nil];
audio.volume=8;
[audio play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the [audio stop]; and set nil to the audio instance when you are navigating to another view. And write this code before you call the next view controller.